# How would you place hyperlinks on 3D Objects/Mesh using ThREE?

Tags: javascript, object, three.js, 3d

I am trying to create a simple box that can link when clicked.

It sounds simple but it didn't work for me so help is appreciated. I've been trying to find answers to this, I don't know what I did wrong. I found like only 2 questions about this on stackoverflow but they still didn't help me answer.

```js
const coolTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('cool.jpg');
const cool = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: Math.random() * 0xffffff
  })
);

cool.userData = {
  URL: "http://stackoverflow.com"
};
scene.add(cool);

function linki() {
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    window.open(intersects[0].object.userData.URL);
  }
}

document.body.onclick = linki
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be only one box then use `window.open(object.URL);` when `pointerdown` event is detected.

```js
let scene, camera, renderer, cube;

window.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => {
  window.open(cube.URL);
});

//

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf79862);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    90,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    1000
  );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const color = 0xffffff;
  const intensity = 1;
  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
  light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
  scene.add(light);

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 0.05);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  cube.position.set(0, 0, -2);
  cube.URL = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  scene.add(cube);

  renderer.setAnimationLoop(loop);
}

function loop() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.145.0/three.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But if you plan to create more URLs you should use Raycaster and check which box was clicked.

```js
let scene, camera, renderer;
let objsToTest = [];

const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
mouse.x = mouse.y = null;

window.addEventListener("pointermove", (event) => {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
});

let selectState = false;

window.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => {
  selectState = true;
});

window.addEventListener("pointerup", () => {
  selectState = false;
});

window.addEventListener("touchstart", (event) => {
  selectState = true;
  mouse.x = (event.touches[0].clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.touches[0].clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
});

window.addEventListener("touchend", () => {
  selectState = false;
  mouse.x = null;
  mouse.y = null;
});

//

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf79862);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    90,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    1000
  );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const color = 0xffffff;
  const intensity = 1;
  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
  light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
  scene.add(light);

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.3, 0.05);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  cube.position.set(-0.5, 0, -2);
  cube.URL = "url1";
  scene.add(cube);

  const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 });
  const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);
  cube2.position.set(0.5, 0, -2);
  cube2.URL = "url2";
  scene.add(cube2);

  objsToTest.push(cube, cube2);

  renderer.setAnimationLoop(loop);
}

function loop() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  updateButtons();
}

function updateButtons() {
  let intersect;
  if (mouse.x !== null && mouse.y !== null) {
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    intersect = raycast();
  }

  if (intersect && selectState) {
    window.open(intersect.object.URL);
  }
}

//

function raycast() {
  return objsToTest.reduce((closestIntersection, obj) => {
    const intersection = raycaster.intersectObject(obj, true);

    if (!intersection[0]) return closestIntersection;

    if (
      !closestIntersection ||
      intersection[0].distance < closestIntersection.distance
    ) {
      intersection[0].object = obj;

      return intersection[0];
    }

    return closestIntersection;
  }, null);
}

init();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.145.0/three.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```